# Hierarchical count query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple hierarchical table (analogous to employee/manager) that I want to show counts of subordinates by parent nodes.

Consider this example from [this article](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-recursive-query/)

```
WITH RECURSIVE subordinates AS (
  SELECT
    employee_id,
    manager_id,
    full_name
  FROM
    employees
  WHERE
    employee_id = 2
  UNION
  SELECT
    e.employee_id,
    e.manager_id,
    e.full_name
  FROM
    employees e
    INNER JOIN subordinates s ON s.employee_id = e.manager_id
) SELECT
    *
  FROM
    subordinates;
```

What i need to do is generate output like this:

```
id    full_name  subordinate_count 
----  ---------  -----------------
1     Alice      42
2     Bob        18
3     Charlie    4
```

Let's say Alice is the CEO and Charlie is a low level manager.

It seems like you have to hard-code a clause in the first half of the union query to get a hierarchical query to work.  I've tried several approaches but nothing is working.  Thanks in advance to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap this query inside an outer query and group over full_name with counts.

example:
select full_name,count(*) 
   from ("your recursive query") outer_query 
  group by outer_query.full_name;

Comment: No, I'm afraid that just gives you one row for every item - i.e. all the counts are 1.